# Is it possible to have an immutable list as the value field inside an immutable map in Java?

Tags: java, list, collections

I have a method that returns an immutable list, and I want to create an immutable map that has `String`s as its keys and the list returned above as value. Is this possible ? Is there a working example of this somewhere?

Comment: Why would it not be possible?

Comment: So would the map just have one entry?

Comment: @ErikMadsen no it will have multiple entires.

Comment: @ErikMadsen I take that back, having just one entry will work for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use Guava, you can probably build your `ImmutableMap` on top of any Map, with a function:

```
Map<String, List<? extends Foobar> maps = ...;
Maps.transformValues(maps, new Function<List<? extends Foobar>, ImmutableList<? extends Foobar>>() {
  public ImmutableList<? extends Foobar> apply(List<? extends Foobar> list) {
    return ImmutableList.copyOf(list);
  }
});
ImmutableMap.copyOf(maps);
```

In pure Java8:

```
maps.replaceAll((key, value) -> Collections.unmodifiableList(value);
Map<String, List<? extends Foobar>> unmodifiableMap = Collections.unmodifiableMap(maps);
```

In pure Java7 (this does not modify the input map):

```
Map<String, List<? extends Foobar>> maps = ...;
Map<String, List<? extends Foobar>> copy = ...;
for (Map<String, List<? extends Foobar>> entry : maps.entrySet()) {
  copy.put(entry.getKey(), Collections.unmodifiableList(entry.getValue()));
}
Map<String, List<? extends Foobar>> unmodifiableMap =     Collections.unmodifiableMap(copy);
```

Comment: In the question he mentions that the list already is immutable.

Comment: Then he should only use `Collections.unmodifiableMap`, or better is there is a single key: `Collections.singletonMap` which is also immutable.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a working example in plain Java:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("Value");

List<String> unmodifiableList = Collections.unmodifiableList(list);

Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("Key", unmodifiableList);

Map<String, List<String>> unmodifiableMap = Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
```

---

I would however recommend using Guava's immutable collections for this kind of task. Documentation can be found [here](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ImmutableCollectionsExplained). The documentation lists the following disadvantages to Java's unmodifiable collections:

> - unwieldy and verbose; unpleasant to use everywhere you want to make defensive copies
> - unsafe: the returned collections are only truly immutable if nobody holds a reference to the original collection
> - inefficient: the data structures still have all the overhead of mutable collections, including concurrent modification checks, extra
>     space in hash tables, etc.

The example above, in Guava would read as:

```
ImmutableMap<String, ImmutableList<String>> map = ImmutableMap
            .of("Key", ImmutableList.of("Value"));
```

Comment: +1 for offering alternatives and additional information.

Comment: +1 for Guava's ImmutableList/Map because it is also explicit.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Use:

```
Collections.unmodifiableMap(someMap);
```

It returns a `Map` view which will throw an `UnsupportedOperationException` if someone tries to modify the map.